# How to avoid rounding up of number in kendo format method?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, number-formatting

I am looking to format the "amount" with maximum 13 decimal precision to populate a grid cell which i'm doing in the following way.

text box is

```
$(gridId + "#Units")
.parent()
.append("<input type='text' id='UnitsA' onkeyup 
              ='checkdigit(this,\"Units\",8,13)' value='" + txval + "'></input>");
```

my .cshtml file has :

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Units)
    .Width("20%")
    .Title("Units")
    .ClientTemplate("#: formatAmountTo13Dec(Units, '') #")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "grid-number" })
    ;
```

the function formatAmountTo13Dec has the following.

```
function formatAmountTo13Dec(data, defaultValue) 
{
    return data != null ? kendo.format("{0:c13}", parseFloat(data)) : defaultValue;
}
```

When i enter -999.9999999999999 in the cell ( 999 followed by 13 decimals) it is formatted by calling the above function.

```
kendo.format("{0:c13}", parseFloat("-999.9999999999999"))
```

However this rounds up the amount and populates the cell with
    `(1,000.0000000000000)`, but the expected amount is `(999.9999999999999)`

To Avoid rounding up, instead of `kendo.format`, i tried `kendo.toString()` ,
But the result to this is `-999.999999999999`, without the brackets for negative number which is required for the amount field in the grid i have.

Can someone please help me out on how to achieve the expected with no rounding and with brackets for negative numbers.